# How can I use List of Scaffold in Scaffold body in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

First of all, in my app when the user draws something and and then press save button, the user user should see the same drawing on his/her phone but on a shorter scale, because he/she can draw more drawings and save them, I wanted to show all of them in a singleChildScrollView. I have tried, but I am getting man errors.
I want to show a grid of different screen on one screen so that whenever the user tap on one of the screens then the screen will expand fully on to the screen.

```
 Builder(
        builder: (context) => Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                height: height,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This below is the code that I tried.
                        widget.drawModel != null
                            ? Transform.scale(
                                scale: 0.5,
                                child: Scaffold(
                                  body: Container(
                                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                      maxHeight:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                              2,
                                      maxWidth:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                    ),
                                    child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: Draw(
                                          points: widget
                                              .drawModel[
                                                  widget.drawModel.length - 1]
                                              .points),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : SizedBox(height: 10),
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        images.length != 0
                            // List view for images
                            ? Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: ImageColumnPad * width),
                                      child: Dismissible(
                                        key: ObjectKey(images[i]),
                                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                                          var item = images.elementAt(i);
                                          deleteItem(i);
                                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                            SnackBar(
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                                              content: Text("Item deleted",
                                                  style:
                                                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                              action: SnackBarAction(
                                                label: "UNDO",
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  undoDeletion(i, item);
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () => {
                                            //TODO: Implement delete function here
                                          },
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Image.file(
                                              images[i],
                                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                ],
                              )
                            : SizedBox(height: 2),
                       ...
...
...
```

Comment: Did you try to change scale factor value.?

Comment: What factor value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the body with Column.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Open route'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```